# How can I manually create a mask for my textbox?

Tags: c#

I'm using the MetroFramework from the NuGet package thing, and it looks great. But it doesn't have a masked textbox. How can I manually make characters like `. - () $` appear in the right place while the user is inputing the numbers?

Maybe there's an easier way to just apply the model of the MetroTextbox to a normal masked textbox, like a css class? That would be easier.

Also, how I'm using this to allow only numbers to be input

```
private void textbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
}
```

How can I also allow one specific character more, like `,`?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at MaskedTextBox implementation on ReferenceSource

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/MaskedTextBox.cs,028398947b443e62

Basically it is using MaskedTextProvider and relies heavily on it's capabilities.